# How to scan a string with white spaces in structure members in C?

Tags: c

```
struct Demo{
   char a[50];
   char b[50];
   int a;
};
```

- Can anyone give the code for this structure Demo where a and b will contains string with different words[white-spaces].

  I tried

  - `scanf("[^\n]s",name.a); //where name is the object`
  - `fgets(name.a,50,stdin);`

**Note :** we can't use `gets` method as well

So, If any other method is there, please provide me.

Comment: how does your input look like? if it's line-by-line, `fgets()` should be good.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `%` somewhere in `scanf(...)`?

Comment: there's no way to give a good answer like this, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Find an example of using the functions you chose, then modify to taste. Maybe https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: `"[^\n]s"` --> `"49[^\n]%*c"`

Comment: "we can't use gets method as well", `gets()` is not anymore in C standard. So this is very good to not use it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sure about the 49 at the start? I'd expect it after the `%`.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sure, as you said :-)

Answer (score 2):

To read a *line* of user input into `char a[50];` with its potential trailing `'\n'` trimmed:

```
if (fgets(name.a, sizeof name.a, stdin)) {
  name.a[strcspn(name.a, "\n")] = '\0'; // trim \n
}
```

Work is needed to cope with consuming excessive long input lines and using the last element of `name.a[]` such as:

```
// Alternative
if (scanf("%49[^\n]", name.a) == 1) {
  // consume trailing input
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    ;
  }
} else {  // Handle lines of only \n, end-of-file or input error
  name.a[0] = '\0';
}
```

---

The `scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", name.a)` approach has trouble in 2 cases:
1) The input is only `"\n"`, nothing is saved in `name.a` and `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.
2) With input longer than 49 characters (aside from the `'\n'`), the `%*c` consumes an extra character, yet the rest of the long input line remains in `stdin`.
Both of these issues can be solves with additional code too.

Comment: If checking the existence of the excess part, change it like `"%49[^\n]%c"` for example. it is also necessary for `fgets`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `"%49[^\n]%*c"` for ignoring the excess part?

Comment: @Yunnosch What I am talking about is that in the OP sample code neither examines whether there is an excess part. In other words, it is about testing not necessarily only for `scanf`.